# State null in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, martyjs

I'm having an issue with creating a component using react and martyjs. I'm sure it is a typo or something but I just can't seem to find it. Although I have a state mixin in the component the state is not being populated and it doesn't look like getState is even being called in the mixin.

Mixin.es6

```
var StateMixin = Marty.createStateMixin({
  listenTo: VideoStore,
  getState: function() {
    return {
      items: VideoStore.list(),
      currentItem: VideoStore.select(),
    }
  }
});
```

State.es6

```
var VideoStore = Marty.createStore({
  displayName: "Store",
  handlers: {
    list: Events.List,
    render: Events.Render
  },
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {  };
  },
  list: function(){
    return this.fetch({
      id: 'list',
      locally: function(){
        if(this.hasAlreadyFetched('list') )
          return this.state.items;
      },
      remotely: function(){
        return  DissolveStateSource.list();
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(){},
  render: function(){}
});
```

Component.es6

```
$( ()=>
React.render(
  <VideosTable/>,
  $("#container")[0]
));

var VideosTable = React.createClass(
{
  mixins: StateMixin,
  render: function() {
    var body = this.state.list.when({  //state is null here
      pending: function(){
        return <span className="ball"></span>;
      },
      failed: function(error){
        return <div className="error">error.message</div>;
      },
      done: function(videos){
        return <div>Videos</div>;
      }
    });

    return <h2>hello</h2>;
  }
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I've added a js bin thing here

http://jsbin.com/lekegicumo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the order of inclusion of JavaScript files was incorrect. Swapping some around fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo in `Mixin.es6` to me.

Change `getState` to `getInitialState`.

Also, in `Component.es6`:

Change `mixins: StateMixin` to `mixins: [StateMixin]`.

Comment: I tried that but getInitialState is not being called either. Nothing in the mixin seems to be getting called.

Comment: @stimms Found another culprit. Check my edited answer.

Comment: tried that too. I actually looked at the marty code and it allows for either an array or a single mixin there. I've added a live version here http://jsbin.com/lekegicumo/2/edit?html,js,console,output so others can see what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

are u using react v0.1.13.0

this is new way to initial your state using 'construct'

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html